# VSCode Minimum TypeScript Project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

EDIT: I don't want or need a browser, I just want to run everything inside of node.

I am trying to create a TS project in VSCode and am having a difficult time of it. I have used VSCode to create and run Angular 7-9 and AngularJS projects, but I don't want to go through all that setup just to run some toy/test TS code. I have never created a "node-only" project before tonight, but I have been able to execute a JS file that was able to read *one* TS file, but not import others.

**I'm looking for the magic combination of .tsconfig settings, package.json settings, and import/require statements that will "just work".**

index.js as it currently sits. I have tried require, this import, and "ts-style" imports, with varying levels of errors (depending on the next 2 files). If I don't import anything, console.log executes just fine. At one point, I was able to "import" (or require?) a compiled TS file *that didn't import any other TS files*, and the code executed just fine.

```js
    import ts from "./dist/start.js";
    console.log("starting");
```

package.json as it currently sits. Adding "type: module" and "--experimental-modules" feels like its gotten me the furthest along, so far.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "go": "tsc & node --experimental-modules index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^3.9.3"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

tsconfig.json as it currently sits. I've tried copying one from an angular project, fiddling with module/moduleResolution/target settings, and a few other things I found online.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

And for completeness's sake, my TS:
cat.ts:

```
    export class Cat {
        constructor(public name: string) {}

        public meow(): void {
            console.log(this.name + " says 'Meow!'");
        }
    }
```

start.ts:

```
    import { Cat } from "./cat"
    const cat = new Cat("sam");
    cat.meow();
    // just in case something needs to be exported.
    export const ts = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Parcel Bundler. https://parceljs.org/

Parcel will automatically install and configure most dependencies for you, including TypeScript. It's super duper easy.

Alternatively go to [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io) and start a new project, maybe Vanilla + TS is what you're looking for. From the project editor you can select File -> Export to ZIP and download the project, including its `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files. (Codesandbox.io uses Parcel under the hood)

There are plenty of TypeScript boilerplate repos out there too, but I like codesandbox.io because it's super fast and easy to get started, and you can still download the project files. And, it basically has the VSCode editor built in.

Comment: Thanks @jered, but neither of those helped. codesandbox.io set up a TS project, but I still couldn't create and/or import TypeScript files. I tried using the environment's package.json and tsconfig.json, but I ended up with the same errors. In addition, it and paceljs seem browser-oriented; I'm just trying to run TS without a browser.

Comment: Ah I didn't catch you were trying to make it node-only. Try these tsconfig settings, the most important one probably being `esModuleInterop` https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks man, but still not working. Depending on whether I have `type: module` in package.json, I get an error that is either "cannot use import statement outside a module" or "Must use import to load ES Module"